# Finding first N natural numbers (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I want to sum over the first n natural numbers.

For example with n = 9 I want to calculate the sum of numbers starting from 1 to 9.

I have tried using a for loop, but I want to know how to find using while loop, with Python 3.

Comment: `def find_sum(n=9):` `return sum(range(n+1))` Of course, there is also a closed form analytical solution that runs much faster: `return n * (n + 1) // 2` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss#Anecdotes Both `range` and `sum` have a `while` loop on the inside.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
def sum_naturals(n):
    first = 1
    sum = 0

    while first <= n:
        sum += first
        first += 1

    return sum


print(sum_naturals(9))  # 45
```